# angular select option not being passed to POST php

Tags: php, angularjs, forms, select, post

This is my form, unfilled
This is the form, filed
The very first form element as shown on the image is a dropdown list (select element with options)

This is the form in question :

This is the select element :

```
<div class="form-group" ng-controller="clubsCtrl">
    <select class="form-control" style="margin-top:10px;"   
             ng-options="club.ID as club.SHORT_NAME for club in clubs"  
             ng-model="selected_club_id">
     </select>
    <label>Odaberite klub kojem igrač pripada</label>
    <p>TEST : ID za odabrani klub :{{selected_club_id}}</p>
</div>
```

There are also other elements in the form,for example:

```
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" 
               id="firstname" 
               ng-model="firstname">
            <label for="firstname">Ime</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" 
           id="lastname" ng-model="lastname">
           <label for="lastname">Prezime</label>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, to fill the options in the select element i am using the
clubsCtrl. I am showing club names, but once a name is clicked, the id is being selected. The label below the select shows that the id really is extracted (see second picture)

This is the call :
    
         class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-raised ink-reaction  pull-right">
          Save

So you can see i am calling the function addPlayer() from the playersCtrl
This is the function :

```
   $scope.addPlayer = function() 
            {
                $http.post('add_player.php',
                {
                    'selected_club_id' : $scope.selected_club_id, 
                    'firstname'        : $scope.firstname, 
                    'lastname'         : $scope.lastname, 
                    'shirt_number'     : $scope.shirt_number,   
                    'position'         : $scope.position, 
                    'age'              : $scope.age, 
                    'national_team'    : $scope.national_team,              
                    'height'           : $scope.height,                 
                    'weight'           : $scope.weight,                 
                    'price'            : $scope.price,                  
                    'ownership'        : $scope.ownership,                  
                    'datum_rodjenja'   : $scope.datum_rodjenja                          
                }               
                ).success(function(data, status, headers, config)
                {           
                    infoTime('<b>Success</b>');
                });
            };
```

This is the add_player.php

```
<?php

// Including database connections
require_once '../assets/database/config.php';

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

    if (count($data) > 0)
    {           
        // escape_string is just a helper function
        $id_team           = escape_string($data->selected_club_id);                    
        $firstname         = escape_string($data->firstname);
        $lastname          = escape_string($data->lastname);
        $shirt_number      = escape_string($data->shirt_number);
        $position          = escape_string($data->position);
        $age               = escape_string($data->age);
        $national_team     = escape_string($data->national_team);
        $height            = escape_string($data->height);
        $weight            = escape_string($data->weight);
        $price             = escape_string($data->price);
        $ownership         = escape_string($data->ownership);
        $datum_rodjenja    = escape_string($data->datum_rodjenja);

        // query is justa helper function   
        $query = query("INSERT INTO players(firstname, lastname, id_team, shirt_number, position, age, national_team, height, weight, price, ownership, date_of_birth, id_status) VALUES('{$firstname}','{$lastname}','{$id_team}','{$shirt_number}','{$position}','{$age}','{$national_team}','{$height}','{$weight}','{$price}','{$ownership}','{$datum_rodjenja}', '1')");


        $insert_result = confirm($query); // confirm = helper function

        # JSON-encode the response
        echo $json_response = json_encode($insert_result);

    }
```

?>

The result:everythng gets inserted right,except the $id_team,
the value thati got from the  element

I have tried a lot of things,nothing seems to work. Ifanybody has got a hint or a suggestion, pleasehelp.

Thanx for all your comments and suggestions.
Sorry formy bad english
Edis

Comment: sorry, seems my images weren't uploaded correctly :(

Comment: form, unfilled:

http://imgur.com/XDrsYBn

Comment: form, filled

http://imgur.com/lFT2ADD

Comment: again,sorry, forgot to show the form in question :

<form novalidate class="form" action="" method="post" >

Comment: have you tried inspecting the select that is generated?

Comment: Do you know at which point the info is being lost? Is `$scope.selected_club_id` set in your controller (log it out) before the `POST` request is sent? Can you verify if the value is actually being sent in the request? Is it being received in the PHP?

Comment: What happens when you add `var_dump($data)` to your php code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

clubsCtrl creates a new scope and thus the selected value is added to a different scope as where you are reading it from when you try to post the value.

(sorry for the short answer, I'm on my phone)

What you'll need to do is use the playersCtrl with the 'as vm' construction and the change the ng-model for the select to 'vm.selected_id'

Let me know if you need more help, I'll grab the laptop and try to elaborate.

**Edit**

Change your route configuration to also include a controllerAs:'vm' for the controller in question. This will add a property named 'vm' to the scope of the controller

Next change the ng-model for the select to be 'vm.selected_id'

Finally in the function that does the post, use $scope.vm.selected_id as the value.

That should work. It could be prettier by avoiding the $scope completely, but I'm on my phone and it's very inconvenient to type code examples :)

Comment: It's OK, any help is welcome
This is what my routing looks like:
`app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
.when('/players',{
 controller: 'playersCtrl',
 templateUrl: '../assets/js/libs/angular/views/players.html'
   })  
   
.when('/add_player', {
 controller: 'playersCtrl',     
        templateUrl: '../assets/js/libs/angular/views/add_player.html'
    })      

.when('/clubs', {
 controller: 'clubsCtrl',
 templateUrl: '../assets/js/libs/angular/views/clubs.html'
   })

otherwise({ redirectTo: '/players' });
`
Should i create a new controller?

Comment: I've edited the answer. The added steps should be all you need to get it to work... Hopefully... Good luck

Comment: I do need a little bit of more help, but please don't hurry, whenever you find the time is ok. In the meantime,i'll google your vm suggetion and see if i can figure it out:

Thanx for your help

Comment: you type fastewr then me my friend. we were writing comments at the same time.I'll try your suggestion wright now. Thanx again

Comment: No worries, I've exchanged all aspirations for a social life for StackOverflow points ;)

Comment: So i tried this

routing

http://imgur.com/JiqeD9H


view:

http://imgur.com/erVTFHk

Controller

http://imgur.com/HqMcr84


But now the dropdown list is not showing any entries at all

Comment: You also added the 'vm.' to the clubs which you shouldn't. And you didn't add the controllerAs to the route configuration. I gotta get some sleep now though. Let me know how it goes. I'll check again in the morning. Good luck with

Comment: I'll try.Thanx for the help Robba.

Comment: Yes,i just did 5 minutes ago.My problem was that i was using one controller at the first line of code in the view (playersControler), but was using another controller when getting the clubs for the dropdown (ClubsCtrl) I couldn't get the vm stuff to work, but i did this: I made sure the view only uses ClubsController,moved the function add_player() from the PlayersController to the ClubsCtrl and that was it. Woudn't have figured it out without your suggestion that clubscontroller creates a new scope though. Now i gotta fix the datepicker  and i'm done with the form. Thanx Robba

Comment: since i'm low with the reputation here (i'm a relatively new user) my vote don't count much, but i did upvote your answer. Is that all or?

Comment: Happy to hear you solved your question. It seems like you're struggling with scopes (as are many who are fairly new with Angular). Check this document, maybe it helps with your understanding: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

Comment: Just started learning angular actually, so yeah, slowly but surely it's starting to make sense. Thanx for the link Robba , will look it up after work for sure.

Comment: Robba, on the same form i have a datepicker (bootstrap) component, and that value is also not being passed to PHP. I read here on stack overflow that datepicker also creates it's own scope, regardless of the controller(s) used in the view?

Comment: That sounds very likely, you probably need to make sure the ng-model for the datepicker component also contains a "dot". the document I linked earlier should help you understand why.

Comment: Fixed the datepicker by using "parent."So now i have my insert of a new player working.

Robba, do you maybe have a link where i can find out more about how to proprerly upload an image to my db?

Comment: That's a pretty complicated subject, but you can have a look at ng-flow https://github.com/flowjs/ng-flow

Comment: Robba, i asked another question, it's the same controller and the form as in this question.A problem with the redirect. Any ideas?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40620524/angular-php-post-redirect-not-working