# Angular PHP post redirect not working

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, redirect, post

I have a hard time making angular edirect after a form does the save to mysql db via php script
This is my routing:

```
var app = angular.module('fantasy_App', ['ui-notification', 'ngAnimate', 'ngRoute']); 
                                            // app is using ngAnimate for animations
                                            // app is using ui-notification for notifications



//This configures the routes and associates each route with a view and a controller
app.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/players',
            {
                controller: 'playersCtrl',
                templateUrl: '../assets/js/libs/angular/views/players.html'
                // controllerAs: 'vm'
            })                  
        .when('/player/:id',
            {
                controller: 'playerCtrl',
                templateUrl: '../assets/js/libs/angular/views/player.html'
            })      
        .when('/add_player',
            {
                controller: 'clubsCtrl',
                templateUrl: '../assets/js/libs/angular/views/add_player.html'              
            })                      
        .when('/clubs',
            {
                controller: 'clubsCtrl',
                templateUrl: '../assets/js/libs/angular/views/clubs.html'
            })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/players' });
});
```

This is my controller that the form is using :

```
app.controller("clubsCtrl",function($scope,$http,Notification,$location){
```

.
.
.

and this is the function that does the save  via pghp script:

```
    $scope.addPlayer = function() 
    {   
        $http.post('add_player.php',
        {
            'selected_club_id' : $scope.selected_club_id, 
            'firstname'        : $scope.firstname, 
            'lastname'         : $scope.lastname, 
            'shirt_number'     : $scope.shirt_number,   
            'position'         : $scope.position, 
            'age'              : $scope.age, 
            'national_team'    : $scope.national_team,              
            'height'           : $scope.height,                 
            'weight'           : $scope.weight,                 
            'price'            : $scope.price,                  
            'ownership'        : $scope.ownership,                                      
            'datum_rodjenja'   : $scope.parent.datum_rodjenja                       
        }               
        ).success(function(data, status, headers, config)
        {           
            //window.location.href = '/players'; 
            //$location.path('players');
            //$location.replace();
            $location.url('/players');

        });
    };
```

As you can see, i tried using both $location and window.location.href

None seem to work, the page does not redirect :(

BTW, the PHP script works, the data is being inserted into the db without any problems whatsoever.

Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: is the success callback called ? Do you see a change in the browser URL bar ? No error in the console ?

Comment: URL has not changed.No error in the console log

Comment: Hi! Try: 'success(function(data, status){...". If you put a console.log() at the   first line of .success does it print any output?

Comment: I addded the line you suggested, and still nothing is being logged to the console